# Run tests with husky pre-push only when there are changes

Tags: git, husky, git-husky

As in the title, at the moment I have configured my app to run tests every time a git push is executed,

```json
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-push": "npm run test:unit"
    }
  }
```

but evidently it does not scale well, the more tests the more time it will take to push, so is there a way I can trigger the tests only if there are changes in the files?

---

eventually I've found that Jest has a nice flag called `--changedSince`
so you can have something like this in your package.json file:

`"test:unit": "test:unit --changedSince=@{push}"`

that will execute only the tests of the files that have been changed making a comparison with the remote HEAD since last push

Comment: The changedSince option sounds great! Consider adding it as an answer, it will let people upvote it ;)

Answer (score 3):

A good option to achieve this is the [prepush-if-changed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prepush-if-changed) package.
It allows you to specify a match pattern for files for which to trigger the hook when changed.

```json
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-push": "prepush-if-changed"
    }
  },
  "prepush-if-changed": {
    "src/**/*.js?(x)": "npm run test:unit"
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have ended up making a small script and using Jest flag `--changedSince=` somthing like this
    `"test:unit-master": "vue-cli-service test:unit --changedSince=origin/master",`
    `"test:unit-remote": "vue-cli-service test:unit --changedSince=@{push}",`

Comment: @Andrea I'm getting an error for this command "fatal: no upstream configured for branch <branch-name>"